# Use local storage to show different content on the next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, local-storage

I'm working on a project in which you select the venues that you've been to in a city and then hit a submit button and, based on where you've been, the next page displays your favorite neighborhood, least visited, etc. etc., not super complicated stuff. I just need the content on the next page to change based on what you select on the first page.

As of now I'm just pushing the name of the most selected neighborhood to localStorage and then trying to show/not show content on the next page based on what's stored. But what I currently have isn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var bigstorage = localStorage.getItem('largest');
if (bigstorage = 'caphill') {
    $('#caphillpage').removeClass('noshow').addClass('show');
} else if (bigstorage = 'fremont') {
    $('#frepage').removeClass('noshow').addClass('show');
}
```

})

LocalStorage is changing as it's supposed to, but as of now it just defaults to the #caphillpage and refuses to change. I'm confident that this is probably the wrong way to do this, and I'm obviously still a little new to all of this so any advice is helpful!

Comment: try `bigstorage == 'caphill'` instead of `bigstorage = 'caphill'`

Comment: Wow. Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how new you are to all of this, but a single = is assignment, double == is value comparison with type conversion (i.e. 2 == '2' resolves to true), and triple === is type comparison as well as value (i.e. 2 === 2 resolves to true, but 2 === '2' resolves to false because one is a Number and one is a String).

Comment: Oh yeah I was familiar, that was just me being dumb. I seriously appreciate it though!

Comment: No problem. Sometimes we all need a second pair of eyes on our code.